# How do I cause objects in my canvas to be attracted to other objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, vector-graphics

I have plotted some words on a canvas. They have random positions. I want them to slowly gravitate towards one another according to a set of rules.

The rules are that some words have to be above, to the left of, to the right of other words.

```
var rules = {
    "id": {
      leftOf: ["title"],
    },
    "title": {
      above: ["userId"],
    },
    "completed": {
      "rightOf": ["title"]
    }
  }
```

How do I add independent gravitational attractions between multiple objects mathematically?

In [my codepen](https://codepen.io/chronological/pen/MWWKqVZ?&editable=true#anon-login), I have just rigged the x and y to the positions rule.

Full code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
// vector code from https://gist.github.com/winduptoy/a1aa09c3499e09edbd33
function Vector(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

/* INSTANCE METHODS */

Vector.prototype = {
    negative: function() {
        this.x = -this.x;
        this.y = -this.y;
        return this;
    },
    add: function(v) {
        if (v instanceof Vector) {
            this.x += v.x;
            this.y += v.y;
        } else {
            this.x += v;
            this.y += v;
        }
        return this;
    },
    subtract: function(v) {
        if (v instanceof Vector) {
            this.x -= v.x;
            this.y -= v.y;
        } else {
            this.x -= v;
            this.y -= v;
        }
        return this;
    },
    multiply: function(v) {
        if (v instanceof Vector) {
            this.x *= v.x;
            this.y *= v.y;
        } else {
            this.x *= v;
            this.y *= v;
        }
        return this;
    },
    divide: function(v) {
        if (v instanceof Vector) {
            if(v.x != 0) this.x /= v.x;
            if(v.y != 0) this.y /= v.y;
        } else {
            if(v != 0) {
                this.x /= v;
                this.y /= v;
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    equals: function(v) {
        return this.x == v.x && this.y == v.y;
    },
    dot: function(v) {
        return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
    },
    cross: function(v) {
        return this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x
    },
    length: function() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.dot(this));
    },
    normalize: function() {
        return this.divide(this.length());
    },
    min: function() {
        return Math.min(this.x, this.y);
    },
    max: function() {
        return Math.max(this.x, this.y);
    },
    toAngles: function() {
        return -Math.atan2(-this.y, this.x);
    },
    angleTo: function(a) {
        return Math.acos(this.dot(a) / (this.length() * a.length()));
    },
    toArray: function(n) {
        return [this.x, this.y].slice(0, n || 2);
    },
    clone: function() {
        return new Vector(this.x, this.y);
    },
    set: function(x, y) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
        return this;
    }
};

/* STATIC METHODS */
Vector.negative = function(v) {
    return new Vector(-v.x, -v.y);
};
Vector.add = function(a, b) {
    if (b instanceof Vector) return new Vector(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    else return new Vector(a.x + b, a.y + b);
};
Vector.subtract = function(a, b) {
    if (b instanceof Vector) return new Vector(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
    else return new Vector(a.x - b, a.y - b);
};
Vector.multiply = function(a, b) {
    if (b instanceof Vector) return new Vector(a.x * b.x, a.y * b.y);
    else return new Vector(a.x * b, a.y * b);
};
Vector.divide = function(a, b) {
    if (b instanceof Vector) return new Vector(a.x / b.x, a.y / b.y);
    else return new Vector(a.x / b, a.y / b);
};
Vector.equals = function(a, b) {
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
};
Vector.dot = function(a, b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
};
Vector.cross = function(a, b) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
};

var texts = ["userId", "id", "title", "completed"];

var rules = {
    "id": {
      leftOf: ["title"],
    },
    "title": {
      above: ["userId"],
    },
    "completed": {
      "rightOf": ["title"]
    }
  }

var vectors = [];
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function Thing(text, x, y) {
  this.text = text;
  this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
  this.velocity = new Vector(getRandomArbitrary(-1, 1), getRandomArbitrary(-1, 1));
  this.thrust = 0.1;
}
var things = texts.map(function (item) {
  return new Thing(item, getRandomArbitrary(0, 900), getRandomArbitrary(0, 300));
}
);

var lookup = {};
for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
    lookup[texts[i]] = things[i];
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '18px serif';

function tick() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 for (var i=0; i < things.length; i ++) {

   var thing = things[i];
   thing.velocity.add(thing.thrust);

   for (var j=0; j < things.length; j++) {
     if (things[j].text == thing.text) { continue }
     if (!rules.hasOwnProperty(thing.text)) { continue }
     var rule = rules[thing.text];

     if (rule.hasOwnProperty( "leftOf")) {
        console.log(thing.text, "must be left of", rule["leftOf"]);
         for (var k=0; k < rule["leftOf"].length; k++ ) {
            if (rule["leftOf"] == things[j].text) {
              console.log("Changing velocity of", thing.text, "to cause it to be left of", things[j].text);
              thing.pos.x = things[j].pos.x - 20;
              thing.pos.y = things[j].pos.y;
            }
         }
     }

        if (rule.hasOwnProperty( "above")) {
        console.log(thing.text, "must be above", rule["above"]);
         for (var k=0; k < rule["above"].length; k++ ) {
            if (rule["above"] == things[j].text) {
              console.log("Changing velocity of", thing.text, "to cause it to be above", things[j].text);
              thing.pos.x = things[j].pos.x;
              thing.pos.y = things[j].pos.y - 30;
            }
         }
        }

        if (rule.hasOwnProperty( "rightOf")) {
        console.log(thing.text, "must be right of", rule["rightOf"]);
         for (var k=0; k < rule["rightOf"].length; k++ ) {
            if (rule["rightOf"] == things[j].text) {
              console.log("Changing velocity of", thing.text, "to cause it to be right of", things[j].text);
              thing.pos.x = things[j].pos.x + 60;
              thing.pos.y = things[j].pos.y;
            }

        }



     }


   }

     thing.pos.add(thing.velocity);
    ctx.fillText(thing.text, thing.pos.x, thing.pos.y);

 }
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, you want to display several words that need be accurately positioned between each other. However, they are initially displayed at random positions. They have to slowly move toward the side they should be on, as if they were attracted. Is it what you want? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Just a few things: `getRandomArbitrary(a, b)` => *random* and *arbitrary* means almost the same here, you could change it to something more meaningful like `getRandomInRange(a, b)` or `getRandomBetween(a, b)`. `function Thing`: this is... *ahem* :) You can use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setInterval()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame, and you should break down your `tick()` function in several smaller functions :)